# Log4net on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net, azure-storage, log4net-configuration

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application that uses Log4net to write logs into text fils.
Now I am moving my solution into Windows Azure Website, but I can't seem to get access to my log files.

Is there any clue ? where will the logs get stored ? Is there other instruction or configuration to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdoNetAppender to write log into Azure SQL database. See this config example:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Notice: use this statement to create Log table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Logger] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
[Exception] [varchar](2000) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
))
```